# How do I construct a delegate and pass it as a parameter to be used in a lambda expression

Tags: delegates, entity-framework-5, lambda

I am refactoring some code
the original statement was

```
var deleteList = new List<FilterParameter>();
foreach (FilterParameter param in FilterParameters)
{
    if (memlist.All(x => x.ParameterName != param.ParameterName))
    {
        deleteList.Add(param);
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something like

```
 var deleteList = ufs.FilterParameters.Where(param => memlist.All(rule2)).ToList();
```

I am unsure how to construct and pass in the delegate

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand you, are you asking how to pass the predicate in the `.Where()`, because that would work like:

```
Func<FilterParameter, bool> predicate = param => memlist.All(x => x.ParameterName != param.ParameterName);

List<FilterParameter> deleteList = FilterParameters.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Is this what you're asking ?

Comment: not quite, it is just the x=>x.parametername !=param.parametername that I want to pass in

Comment: Not sure if the scope of `param` and `x` allows them to be extracted out of this context. I don't think it's possible. The closes thing you can get to (that I know of) would be a helper method to create the predicate by passing the one from the current context.